# Problems running certain queries

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm trying to run the following two sql queries on data.stackexchange.com/gaming :

http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/s/86/most-and-least-dangerous-tags-to-answer-among-the-tags-with-1000-questions

http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/s/85/posts-with-many-thank-you-answers

And in both cases I get a section of the code as the result. I'm obviously doing something stupid. The question is what?

(In the second question I do see "[Post Link]" but I'm not sure what data is expected there).

Comment: In case of thank you, I guess there simply aren't any posts to return

Comment: Slightly strange don't you think? Wouldn't the person who wrote the query notice this himself?

Comment: Those queries were likely originally written against the StackOverflow database.  The queries saved on data.stackexchange can be run on any of the SE sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There are no tags with 1000 questions on Gaming (StarCraft 2 has 598 as of this morning).
2. There are no answers on Gaming that are less than 200 characters and contain the string "hank".

Comment: Aha. That solves both of them. Thanks.